# Using GestureRecognizer on an ImageView in a scrollview

Tags: ios, ios4, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a horizontal, paged scroll view that houses multiple view controllers, each of which contains a UIImageView. Within each view controller, I am adding a Tap GestureRecognizer to the ImageView so I can perform a specific action when the image is tapped/double tapped.

However, the ImageView gesture recgonizers don't seem to be firing, and therefore the selectors are not getting called.

I anticipate it may have something to do with the Imageview's being housed in the scrollview, but I am not sure where to start. Is there anything specific I need to do to ensure that the gesture recognizer gets called for each imageview within the scrollview?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps your UIImageView is not configured to receive user interaction

> UIImageView has in default
>   userInteractionEnabled set to NO. I
>   would try to change it to YES.

[UIgestureRecognizer in a view inside a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005903/uigesturerecognizer-in-a-view-inside-a-uiscrollview)

Comment: Did this answer your question?  If so, please mark as the answer, if not, post the answer you found below to help the community.